# Split a string into multiple arrays based on a variable (incremental) delimiter

Tags: php, json, wikipedia-api

I'm trying to convert some wikipedia data (a table) into html format using the wikipedia API. I've got quite far into it really and think I'm fairly near the end (famous last words...) 
I'm having trouble however with converting the string of data into arrays based on the ranking of the airport. The data spits out rankings of the busiest airports, and I want to split the results into arrays based on ranking ( so First array = first airport and its details, second = second airport etc. etc.).

Code:

```
$endpoint = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?';

$worlds_busiest_airports_url = 'action=parse&page=List_of_busiest_airports_by_passenger_traffic&section=1&prop=wikitext&format=json';

$response = file_get_contents($endpoint . $worlds_busiest_airports_url);
$response_decoded = json_decode($response,true);

//echo "<pre>";
//print_r($response_decoded);
//echo "</pre>";

$data = $response_decoded['parse']['wikitext']['*'];

$start = strpos($data,'1.');

$data = substr($data,$start);

$strlen = strlen($data);

function index_data($data,$count,$strlen) {

    while ($count <= 19) {
        $count ++;
        $delimiter = $count . '.';


    }
}

index_data($data,0);
```

I've got a delimiter that should increment each time the correct number is reached. I just don't know how to then get the characters between these delimiters and convert them to an array. I've tried using explode but just ended up returning individual characters.

This is the format of the data (though obviously there are more records:

```
 1.|| {{flagicon|USA}} [[Hartsfield–Jackson Atlanta International 
Airport]]||[[Atlanta]], [[Georgia (U.S. state)|Georgia]]|| United 
States||ATL/KATL||104,171,935||{{steady}}||{{increase}}2.6%
|-
|2.|| {{flagicon|PRC}} [[Beijing Capital International Airport]]||[[Chaoyang 
District, Beijing|Chaoyang]]-[[Shunyi District|Shunyi]], [[Beijing]]|| 
China||PEK/ZBAA||94,393,454||{{steady}}||{{increase}}5.0%
|-
```

etc.

Any Advice? I've also tried for loops, iterating through the string until I found the delimiter, but again I just don't really know the string functions well enough to achieve anything.

Comment: are these edits to remove three words at the end of the question really necessary?!

Comment: Why would you do that, instead of fetching the parsed HTML from the API?